# Python Spatial Autoregressive model

Tags: python, spatial, correlation, statsmodels, autoregressive-models

I have set up in Python a Cyclostationary Autoregressive Process of order 1 (AR-1) in order to generate multiple future wind speed time series. Until now, obviously, I examine the temporal auto-correlation of my wind speed data having a univariate case just for one single pixel.

Assuming that I have time series for multiple pixels (wind speed patterns) and I want to extend this procedure in space in order to generate artificial time series not only correlated in time but also in space. Which is the most appropriate and "easily" handled methodology?

I am not an expert on this kind of statistical methods so I am a bit lost and I apologize for any mistakes. I studied for Space-Time Autoregressive models (STAR - [PySAL](https://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)), Vector Autoregressive (VAR) models, Gaussian Random Fields ([SkiKit-Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html)) etc. but I see that the most appropriate methodology for this kind of autoregression is mostly based on:

- Vector Autoregressive models (VAR) using [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) where my Multivariate case is based on all neighboring pixels time series is that correct?

I am just trying to find which is the most appropriate procedure to study Spatial Autocorrelation in an Autoregressive process considering that I am not an expert in this kind of analysis. I have already seen this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47202/var-vs-star-for-space-time-autoregression-in-python) but I couldn't figure out which one is the best option.